# How to Block main Thread when we use DownloadFileAsync

Tags: c#, multithreading

In my project I have a section to Download File . I use `DownloadFileAsync()` Method to Download and Add Two Event Handler :

- DownloadProgressChanged
- DownloadFileCompleted

I want when Use DownloadFileAsync to Download File ,Block main thread , because i don't want users can click on the button before download completed.

Part of my code:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(ProgressChange);
        webClient.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(Completed);
        Uri Url = new Uri(txtUrl.Text.Trim());
        webClient.DownloadFileAsync(Url,FolderDialog.SelectedPath+System.IO.Path.GetFileName(txtUrl.Text) );
```

How can I do this ? 
I searched on the internet but I can't found useful Result. thanks

Comment: Blocking the entire UI to disable a specific button seems... heavy handed.

Comment: ... and is not really something you should do considering UX. Just disable the button, so the user knows he can't click it. Also, there's really no point in fetching your data asynchronously if you're blocking the thread while waiting for it to finish. Fetching synchronously would result in almost the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's better to disable controls than to deliberately block the UI thread.  In Windows Forms, this can be done by setting `Control.Enabled` to `false`.  I'm not familiar with WPF so can't say what you'd do there.  Anyway, disabling controls gets you the behavior you desire without stopping the normal processing of events, so the user can still move the window, it'll still repaint, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to disable the whole thread, just disable the button. If you really want to disable the main thread just call the thread.sleep but that defeats the purpose of downloading async as the end result is the same as downloading normally.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, in my experience the general way of doing this is:

1. Button is disabled **before** doing any downloading.
2. Download begins.
3. Download completion event handler enables the button again.
4. Additionally, in the event of a problem the button should be enabled.

Comment: Given that you know others have already said it, why did you say it *again*?

Comment: @Servy I felt I could _elaborate_ a little on the end to end steps, rather than just telling the OP to disable the button.  But thanks for reminding me why I don't bother contributing here, I'll go back to just leeching the answers.